# How do I search for a GridView located in a user control from a parent page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, web-controls

I have a placeholder in my webpage, and I dynamically bind user controls to it.

I try to loop through all the controls inside my placeholder and get the control ID, which is the ID of my user control.  The control ID is basically the name of my usercontrol with underscores; so if my user control's name is dynamicControl.ascx, then in my control.ID I get ASP.dynamicControl_ascx.  Now do I need to load my user control again?  If so how do I do it, and how do I type cast it, and also how do I find the gridview inside my usercontrol?

The user control is a gridview and I need to retrieve the values entered in textboxes inside the control.

Answer (score 2):

Several steps/concepts required here...

1. Understanding page life cycle and knowing WHERE/When to bind your dynamic components.  Normally this can be accomplished by doing your bind within Page_Init so that they are present on postback viewstate binding. Without this consideration your grid may not be present and most always will be empty if it is present.  There are times when just moving your binding into Page_Init is not possible... and in these cases one should google on Biding Dynamic Controls.  There are tons of examples on how to address the various approaches to getting dynamic content returned on postback.
2. Thre is no need to walk the child controls list - look into FindControl. Assuming the Grid when created was assigned the ID of 'MyGrid' and the User control is named MyUserControl... To locate the Grid on postback (assuming viewstate issue in number one above is handled) - you can simply use:
   `grid = MyUserControl.FindControl("MyGrid")`

Of course if there is no grid object returned then the MyGrid is not present.

Hope this helps.....

Comment: this is my code... I am not able to find...  yes I load my placeholder function on Init and I see my grid on postback ....

Comment: returns 0rows
 
        DataTable questionResp = new DataTable();
         String questionLabel = String.Empty;
                  foreach (Control ctrl in phReqForm.Controls)
         {       foreach (Control ctrlChild in ctrl.Controls)

             {if (ctrlChild is ASP.dynamiccontrolfr_ascx)
              {  UserControl uc = new UserControl();
    uc = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl("DynamicControlFR.ascx");
     GridView gv = ((GridView)uc.FindControl("gvFR"));
    
         string test = gv.Rows.Count.ToString();
         questionResp.Rows.Add(test, test, questionLabel, test);

    }}}

Answer (score 1):

This will help you
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-cs

This way i was able to find control value which is added dynamically.
just need to provide control id you want to find.
here my panel id was **plnall** and textbox id is **txt_id** and **cplacehld** is content placeholder id,**ctl00**  is masterpage id

```
MasterPage ctl00 = FindControl("ctl00") as MasterPage;

            ContentPlaceHolder cplacehld = ctl00.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder2") as ContentPlaceHolder;
 Panel panel1 = cplacehld.FindControl("plnall") as Panel;
 TextBox txt = cplacehld.FindControl("txt_id") as TextBox;
                    value = txt.Text;
```

Comment: Hi Ivan Karajas,

Can i have your email because i cant paste my code here due to character limitation... i can explain you in email my scenario and what i am trying to do...

Comment: i couldnt paste my complete code but the idea my gridview is inside the usercontrol and there are many user controls in my application.. depending on certain conditions i bind a user control to my placeholder on my web page. i want to save the data from the usercontrol's gridview on pressing save button which is on my webpage. so i need to retrieve all the values of my gridview rows and save them...but i cant find my grid. I can find something like ASP.dynamicControl_ascx which is name of my usercontrol without the underscores and the prefix asp... this is very frustrating... please help